# Getting count of different records from single table-MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am having the table named `tbl_sales` and this table contains the fields `active` and `is_featured`. Now i am trying to get the count of the records where `active=0`, `active=1`, `is_featured=1` and `is_featured=0`. How can i get this in a single query. Can somebody show me a query to get this. I am a newbie to programming and in a self learning process. Need solutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `SUM`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(active=0,1,0)) as nonActiveCount,
  SUM(IF(active=1,1,0)) as activeCount,
  SUM(IF(featured=0,1,0)) as nonfeaturedCount,
  SUM(IF(featured=1,1,0)) as featuredCount
FROM myTable
```

The `IF(active=0,1,0)` says "if active is 1, return a 1. otherwise, return a 0".

The `SUM` around it adds up all the numbers, which are 0 if non-active and 1 if active (etc).

Comment: +1 very nice solution, but doesn't it have to iterate trough ALL records without possible use of indexes?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - Thanks very much, that serves the purpose.

Comment: @Vyktor - I don't know, I'm clueless when it comes to indices. I suppose one could run EXPLAIN on the query?

Comment: @JimmyM could you please run `EXPLAIN ...` (paste query there) and somehow paste result here (or on pastebin and put link here..., add `@vyktor` to comment so I'd get notification)

Comment: Ah, your solution (mathematical.coffee) has better results in benchmarks, I wasn't expecting that :) @JimmyM, go with this one :) somehow it's smart enough to use indexes. Add index on those two fields.

Comment: @Vyktor Yes indeed, i will be using indexes as you said.

Comment: Actually, in MySQL you can just use `sum(active)` and `sum(not(active))` instead of `SUM(IF(active=1,1,0))` and  `SUM(IF(active=0,1,0))`. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c06ad/1). In case when there could be another values, it still can be shorten, for example, to `sum(active = 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will do.

```
select active, is_featured, count(*) from tbl_sales
group by active, is_featured
having (active=0 or active=1) and (is_featured=0 or is_featured=1);
```

**Update:**

This SQL will group all rows with all four combinations

```
active=0; is_featured=0
active=0; is_featured=1
active=1; is_featured=0
active=1; is_featured=1
```

and provide the count for each group. Since there is a having clause, it will restrict to have rows only columns having values 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
SELECT
  cnt.sq1 AS active,
  cnt.sq2 AS inactive,
  cnt.sq3 AS featured,
  cnt.sq4 AS not_featured
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_sales WHERE active = 1
) AS sq1
JOIN FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_sales WHERE active = 0
) AS sq2
JOIN FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_sales WHERE is_featured= 1
) AS sq3
JOIN FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_sales WHERE is_featured= 0
) AS sq4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT active,is_featured,count(*) FROM tbl_sales GROUP By active,is_featured
```

sample output:

```
+--------+-------------+----------+
| active | is_featured | count(*) |
+--------+-------------+----------+
|      0 |           0 |        7 |
|      0 |           1 |        6 |
|      1 |           0 |      204 |
|      1 |           1 |       66 |
+--------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: if you have values apart from 0 and 1 in active and is_featured columns, then you will get all such rows

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at [mySQL's `GROUP BY` modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) you'll find there an example with *multiple `GROUP BY` columns* (it's the only one official example I found):

```sql
mysql> SELECT year, country, product, SUM(profit)
    -> FROM sales
    -> GROUP BY year, country, product;
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| year | country | product    | SUM(profit) |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| 2000 | Finland | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | Finland | Phone      |         100 |
| 2000 | India   | Calculator |         150 |
| 2000 | India   | Computer   |        1200 |
| 2000 | USA     | Calculator |          75 |
| 2000 | USA     | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2001 | Finland | Phone      |          10 |
| 2001 | USA     | Calculator |          50 |
| 2001 | USA     | Computer   |        2700 |
| 2001 | USA     | TV         |         250 |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Take a look how `WITH ROLLUP` works (you may and probably will find it useful).

So building your query like this:

```sql
SELECT active, is_featured, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM tbl_sales
GROUP BY active, is_featured WITH ROLLUP
```

Should always return 4 rows which would look like:

```
+--------+--------------+-----+
| active | is_feautured | cnt |
+--------+--------------+-----+
| 1      | 1            | 5   |
| 1      | 0            | 8   |
| 0      | 1            | 0   |
| 0      | 0            | 7   |
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

And than with simple loop (example in php, do it in whatever you need:

```php
// Get results from DB
$sql = 'SELECT active, is_featured, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM tbl_sales
    GROUP BY active, is_featured WITH ROLLUP';

$q = mysql_query( $sql);

// Initialize values, two array keys 0: value 0, 1: value 1
$active = array( 0, 0);
$is_featured = array( 0, 0);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q)){
    $active[ $row['active']] += $row['cnt'];
    $is_featured[ $row['is_feautured']] += $row['cnt'];
}
```